# Resident (RES) memory bloat in 1 of 15 sidekiq workers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, memory-leaks, sidekiq

I have a Rails app running on an Ubuntu EC2 instance.

It has 15 Sidekiq workers, and it appears that 1 of those Sidekiq processes always ends up consuming a lot of memory, even when it runs out of jobs to run.

After a fresh Sidekiq restart, the Sidekiq processes each use approx. 500MB of Resident memory. Over the course of a day, I'll end up with one of them up to about 2GB of Resident memory, even when I then go clear the Sidekiq queue.

This eventually results in the machine running out of memory, and restarting Sidekiq resolves the issue.

Is it normal for 1 of the Sidekiq processes to climb higher than the rest? If not, how can I figure out what's causing this?

Thanks

Comment: https://schneems.com/2019/11/07/why-does-my-apps-memory-usage-grow-asymptotically-over-time/

Comment: https://www.speedshop.co/2017/12/04/malloc-doubles-ruby-memory.html